# XCode warning explaingen and corrected? DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT

Tags: xcode

I got this warning:

```
DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT should be set to dwarf-with-dsym for all configurations. This could also be a timing issue, make sure the Fabric run script build phase is the last build phase and no other scripts have moved the dSYM from the location Xcode generated it. Unable to process Project.app.dSYM at path /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-rgomisstclrabvudqmbwooyudhxw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Project.app.dSYM
```

Can anyone help me correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the Debug Information Format under Build Settings to dwarf-with-dysym, both for Debug and Release modes.

A sample project with the settings highlighted in blue can be seen below:

[image]